# Regex - simple phone number

Tags: regex

I know there are a ton of regex examples on how to match certain phone number types. For my example I just want to allow numbers and a few special characters. I am again having trouble achieving this.

Phone numbers that should be allowed could take these forms

```
5555555555
555-555-5555
(555)5555555
(555)-555-5555
(555)555-5555 and so on
```

I just want something that will allow [0-9] and also special characters '(' , ')', and '-'

so far my expression looks like this

```
/^[0-9]*^[()-]*$/
```

I know this is wrong but logically I believe this means allow numbers 0-9 or and allow characters (, ), and -.

Comment: I would also recommend searching for the characters . And + since many times those two are used either for entering country codes or just different style. Another option that I've used before is to just strip out all non digits and then just check the digits for correct length. Also, I am glad you are doing this. Is it so annoying for many websites or programs that force you into a specific format, when the computer can easily check!

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: A list of regexes for evaluating how cool/memorable phone numbers are: https://github.com/fulldecent/google-voice-numbers/blob/master/2.%20Find%20cool%20numbers.md

Answer (score 5):

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$
```

- `\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}` three digits with or without `()` - The simpler regex would be `\(?\d{3}\)?` but that would allow `(555-5555555` and `555)5555555` etc.
- An optional `-` followed by three digits
- An optional `-` followed by four digits

Note that this would still allow `555555-5555` and `555-5555555` - I don't know if these are covered in your *and so on* part

Comment: Thanks this is correct I think my question was not phrased properly. I did not need to designate a specific length on the numbers to allow for foreign phone numbers etc. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4):

This match what you want numbers,(, ) and -

```
/^[0-9()-]+$/
```

Comment: For this I want to allow spaces and +m sign also. like +91 555 555 555. Can you please suggest me the good one.

Comment: This is almost what I want but I want to enforce it to end with a number

Answer (score 3):

> ^[0-9-+\s]+$

---

> 06754654
> +54654654
> +546 546 5654 43534 +
> +09945 345 3453 45

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a stray `^` in there? I think you meant `[()-]` This is actually making you have to have two beginning-of-strings in the regex, which will never match.

Also, `\d` is a nice shortcut for `[0-9]`. They are exactly the same.

Also, this will only match a bunch of numbers, then a bunch of `(` or `)` or `-`. Something like: `1294819024()()()()()-----()-` would match. I think you want the whole thing to be able to repeat, something like: `^(\d*[()-]*)*$`. Now, you can match repeating sequences of this.

Now, it is important to notice that nested `*` are typically inefficient, we can realize that we are just wanting to match any digit and the punctuation you want: `[\d()-]*`

Comment: Won't the [^()-] mean to NOT match those characters?

Answer (score 0):

For digits you can use `\d`. For more than one digit, you can use `\d{n}`, where `n` is the number of digits you want to match. Some special characters must be escaped, for example `\(` matches `(`. For example: `\(\d{3}\)\-\d{3}\-\d{4}` matches (555)-555-5555.

Answer (score 0):

The second carat (afaik) is going to break anything you do since it means "start of string".

What you appear to be asking for therefore is:

- start of string, followed by...
- any number of numeric characters, followed by...
- start of string, followed by...
- any number of '(',')', or '-' characters, followed by...
- end of string

Which won't work even if that second carat does nothing, because you're not accounting for *anything* after the first '(',')', or '-', and in fact will probably only validate an empty string if that.

You want `/^[0-9()-]+$/` for a very crude pattern which will "work".

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing US only number the best solution is to strip out all the non-digit characters and then just test to see if the length == 10.