# Rails validate Phone number via regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app where I want to force/validate a certain format of a phone number that being: 222-222-2222

I'm really bad with regex and having a hard time figuring out a regex pattern that matches 222-222-2222

I've tried a few answers here on Stack but they weren't what I was looking for.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex - simple phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256547/regex-simple-phone-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is exactly so, then you need:

```
/\A\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\z/
```

`\A    :` meaning the match should start at start of string
`\d{3} :` 3 numeric digits
`-     :` -
`\z    :` meaning the match should end at end of string

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and works perfectly.  I'm playing with Rubular to practice my Regex.  Thanks for explaining it to me, it really made sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if subject =~ /^d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/
    # Yes, it matches!
else
    # Nah... No match. 
end
```