# What is the regex pattern to allow numbers and some special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to allow numbers and some special characters like `+` `.` `-` `(` `)`.
The Phone number formats my like.

```
9999 999 999
9999999999
999999
+91 99 99 99 9999
999.999.999
99 (999) 99 99 etc..
```

Like any format. Is there any one Help me.

I have tried Lot number of answers in stack overflow but I can't get better one.

Comment: did you want to match only numbers without special characters?

Comment: `I have tried Lot number of answers in stack overflow` - show them, we might be able to find something simple to fix

Comment: @lan. similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256547/regex-simple-phone-number.. any many are there

Comment: @chandu I meant show your attempts. Surely, regular expressions from other answer won't perfectly fit your need

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match the lines which contains numbers and special characters(`.+)(-`),

```
^[-()+ .]?(?:[0-9]+[-()+ .]+)+[0-9]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/20)

Comment: also you can escape special characters (for example - .) with backslash \.

Comment: `-` don't need escaping if we put it at the first or at the last in char class.

Comment: @Avinash Raj. your solution is great. but here It support consecutive special characters. can we avoid those things

Comment: @chandu for this `99 (999)` we need a consecutive special characters.

Comment: @AvinashRaj. good answer but not support two dots . and two + and (). like +555(555).4114656.()5454

Comment: @chandu give some example  list of all possibilities.

Comment: @Avinash Raj allow only single + sign that to at starting position. format must start with number or + and not allow two consecutive dots .. and () and --