# Regex for phones at Belarus

Tags: regex, html

I use masked input in browser and I want to use regex inside html5 attribute on input field - `pattern`. Phone number example:

`+375 (33) 302-66-60`

Now I have [regex](https://regex101.com/r/bZ2hS9/1):

`^\D*(?:\d\D*){12,}$`

But I want to check codes inside `()`. Now in Belarus we have only four possible code: `17`, `29`, `33`, `44`.

I will add correct answer to the library of regex at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) for the keywords `Belarus` and `phone`. Thank you for answer.

Comment: ok, i guess +375 is fixed, and (33) can be 17, 29, 33 or 44 and the rest is 7 digits is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - simple phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256547/regex-simple-phone-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go with something along the lines of

```
^\+375 \((17|29|33|44)\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$
```

This regex captures the national code `+375` if you want to make it optional, you could always put it in parenthesis and add a `?` after.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this snippet

> ^+375 ((17|29|33|44)) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$

`^\+375` catches the country calling code `(17|29|33|44)` catches the four different area codes and `[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$` the rest.